# Regex for all characters before (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Having a little trouble with targeting "group of characters that might contain a hypen before" with regex. I'm performing this on a string of query params. I might have something like this:

```
http://www.example.com?page=5&items=ASC&state=NY
```

I'm trying to find all the characters before `=ASC`, so in this case it would be `items`.

Because `items` is dynamic, this could change, so would like to be able to target any word that could be placed before `=ASC` (including hyphens).

Here are a few examples of other cases I need to meet:

```
http://www.example.com?status=ASC&state=HI
```

Should capture `status`

```
http://www.example.com?page=5&e-mail=ASC&state=NY
```

Should capture `e-mail`

I currently have:

```
const url = 'http://www.example.com?page=5&items=ASC&state=NY';
const newUrl = url.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]=(?=ASC)/, 'test');
```

but it's not working.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of doing this with regex, you should [parse the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/979975/1048572)

Comment: @KevinB That's a lookahead expression

Comment: I think you're looking for `/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?==ASC)/`. Notice the repetition of the character group, and the equals sign that was moved into the lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx is not my strong point.

But I think this does something like what your after..

breakdown..

`(&\?)` first looks for a ? or &..  this becomes the first capture group.
`([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)=ASC` is looking for your *string=ASC*,  this becomes the second capture group that we will ignore
`(&|$)` look for & or end of line, 3rd capture group

`$1test=ASC$3` =  use first capture group, add `test=ASC`, and then add 3rd capture group..

```js
var
  urls = [
    'http://www.example.com?page=5&items=ASC&state=NY',
    'http://www.example.com?items=ASC&page=5&state=NY',
    'http://www.example.com?page=5&state=NY&items=ASC',
    'http://www.example.com?page=5&e-mail=ASC&state=NY'];
    
urls.forEach((url)=>{
  console.log(url.replace(/(&|\?)([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)=ASC(&|$)/, '$1test=ASC$3'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your search text are only urls you can parse it easily.

Something like that:

```js
const urls = [
  'http://www.example.com?page=5&items=ASC&state=NY',
  'http://www.example.com?items=ASC&page=5&state=NY',
  'http://www.example.com?page=5&state=NY&items=ASC',
  'http://www.example.com?page=5&e-mail=ASC&state=NY'
];

const result = urls.map((url) => url.split('?')[1])
  .map((search) => search.split('&')
    .map((parts) => parts.split('='))
    .filter((parts) => parts.indexOf('ASC') > -1)
    .map(ascParts => ascParts[0]));

console.log(result);
```